# New Twist - sum of numbers printed on billiard balls in a bag

Tags: combinations

Given that all the balls in a bag have one number (either 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4) printed on them, and given that there are 30 balls in the bag, how many possible combinations of balls can be taken from the bag where the sum of the numbers printed on the balls adds up to 30?  The twist is the sum of the numbers...

I am unsure how to tackle this one.

Comment: It depends on which numbers the balls have. E.g. if they all have a $0$, then the answer is $0$.

Comment: There are 30 balls but only five numbers. How many times does each number occur? Do they all occur the same number of times?

Comment: Or are you asking about all possible combinations that might arise for all possible labelings of the balls, not just for one given labeling?

Comment: Sorry, I mis-stated the problem.  30 balls will be drawn from a bag that has enough quantity of each number of balls, so that no matter how many it takes to reach a sum of thirty, there will always be enough.  How many  combinations are possible?   Thanks for taking the time to help with this.